# How to find the the value of $x$ that minimise $\mathsf E\left[(X-x)^2\right]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given $X\in {\mathcal L}^2(\Omega ,P)$ and:
$$f\colon {\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb R}, \qquad f(x):=\mathsf E\left[(X-x)^2\right].$$

How should I find the x that minimise $f(x)$? I tried to differentiate it as well as expanding the expectation but it seems to lead to nowhere. How should I think of this problem?

Comment: Open parenthesis under expectation, then use linearity and this way you will be able to differentiate

Comment: Show that the above equals $E[X-E(X)]^2 + (E(X) - x)^2$ and deduce that the minimum is achieved at $x=E(X)$.

Comment: I think differentiation is a wrong approach which kind of misses the point..

Answer (score 4):

Try to "see through the notation", and you can actually understand that your $f$ is nothing more than a simple quadratic function. $E[X]$, $E[X^2]$, etc, are just some constant numbers.

Explicitly, you can expand

$$ E[(X-x)^2]=E[X^2-2xX+x^2]=E[X^2]-2xE[X]+x^2$$

where in the last equality I used linearity of expectation. This is a simple parabola, whos minima is at $"-b/2a"$, which in our case is $2E[X]/2=E[X]$.

More intuitiviely, this result of course makes sense, as the expectation should be "the best estimation" for $X$ (thus in average, $X$ deviates from it the least).

Comment: "Best" in a specific sense.  The expectation (arithmetic mean) minimises the expected square of the difference, but not for other distances: for example the median would minimise the expected absolute difference.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, you are right :)